# Explicitly_shared action not working properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/maxxxotime:uploaded?method=post&photo=http://domain.com/&image[0][url]=http://domain.com/image/photo.jpg&image[0][user_generated]=true&explicitly_shared=true&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN`

I am using the above but it is only showing up on my activity feed, how to properly post the data so it appears in newsfeed too?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the facebook documentation is incorrect. I believe using fb:explicitly_shared=true should work